I'm doing JUnit testing in Java and I'm testing for if I can add in a custom array list element at a certain place, why aren't the elements adding in?
I'm trying to test the add at a specific position method but when I look through the debugger it seems as if the elements didn't get added into the list in the first place. What can I do to figure out why that is and correct that? Also, I do know that when I do a Junit test to add an element to the custom list in general than that test passes but when I do a test to add the element in a specific position than that test fails.
This one passes
 @Test
        public void testAdd() {
            CustomList<Integer> list = new CustomArrayList<>();
            
            // Test adding an item to the list
            assertTrue(list.add(5));
            assertTrue(list.add(1));
            assertTrue(list.add(2));
            assertTrue(list.add(3));
             
           
    

}

This One Fails
 @Test
     public void AddAtPosition() {
         CustomList<Integer> list = new CustomArrayList<>();
         
         // Test adding an item at a specific position
         list.add(0, 10); // Adding 10 at position 0
         list.add(1, 20); // Adding 20 at position 1
         
         // Check if the elements are added at the correct positions
         assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(10), list.get(0)); // Check if 10 is at position 0
         assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(20), list.get(1)); // Check if 20 is at position 1
         
         // Add a new element at position 1 to replace existing element 20
         list.add(1, 40); // Adding 40 at position 1 (replacing existing element 20)
         
         // Check if the element at position 1 has been replaced correctly
         assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(40), list.get(1)); // Check if 40 is at position 1 after replacement
         
         // Verify the size of the list
         assertEquals(2, list.getSize()); // Check if the size of the list is 2 after the addition
     }

This is the add method
    public boolean add(int index, Object element) {
        // Check if index is within bounds
        if (index < 0 || index > size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds");
        }
        
        // Check if array is full, increase capacity if necessary
        if (size == items.length) {
            increaseCapacity();
        }
        
     // Shift elements to the right to make space for the new item
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= index; i--) {
            items[i+1] = items[i];
        }

        
        // Add the new item at the specified index
        items[index] = element;
        size++;
        
        return true;
    }

Here is my GitHub for all the relevant files and code : https://github.com/computersciencehelpman/Assignment7
I was expecting the test case to pass where I add in the element at a specific index, however, the element didn't add in at all.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please see: What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?
Also add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Is your add(int, Object); method suppose to replace the value at the given index as you wrote in your question? Usually it inserts the new value at the given index, shifting all existing values after that location one position up.
